# I need only 4 mappers and 2 reducers in AWS but that does not happen?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

How do u make sure
only 4 map and 2 reduce are there
because when i use 1 large instance
it sometimes give me 6 map 2 reduce
random no.
i tried putting mapred.map.tasks=4
in the extra args while settingup the job
that also didn`t work

Answer (score 0):

Try to set number of mapper and reducers with bootstrap action.

```
     elastic-mapreduce --create \
     --name "cluster_name" \
     --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop --args -m,mapred.map.tasks=4,-m,mapred.reduce.tasks=2,-m,mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=4,-m,mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=2
```